# Was there a deleted scene or missing footage from Goldeneye involving a car?

Tags: james-bond, goldeneye, deleted-scenes

I noticed that in the film Goldeneye, Q takes the time to show James Bond not only a new BMW, but one that he says shows something he's proud of, SAT missiles in the hood.

But the car never appears again the rest of the movie. It's strange from a film watching perspective that not only is this car introduced but specific features are outlined.. which is typically a foreshadowing it's going to be used later in the film.

Is there missing scenes or removed footage of a car chase or action scene involving the car?

All we get is a playful car scene with Bond and Xenia Onnatop but that's during his psyche evaluation and before Q introduced the car.

Comment: Isn’t there a scene where he’s remotely driving it around a multi-storey car park with a phone? I remember it at is was full or product placement for the new set Nokia at the time.

Comment: @Darren That's *TOMORROW Never Dies*.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the DVD commentary ([via Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GoldenEye#Product_placement))

> the Z3 does not have much screen time and none of the gadgets are used, which Martin Campbell attributed to the deal with BMW coming in the last stages of production.

Answer (score 4):

It is shown later in the movie at about 1h 34m when Bond and his female companion are meeting Wade, the CIA agent who is in the airplane that overflies them. Later, Wade gets in the car and drives off, and they use the plane to track down the villain's base. There is no deleted scene, according to any online source, with the missiles being used.

Comment: I remember the scene, but the car doesn't involve an action scene and the SAT missiles being mentioned by Q don't get fired at all. I'm just curious if there was a scene involving the car but maybe as a last minute decision removed it

Comment: There is not a car chase or action scene in the move with the BMW Z3. Except he was chasing the plane that Wade was landing but did not use any of the missles etc the car was suppose to have had.

Comment: Dean I know that. My question is asking if there's a missing outtake.. I mentioned that the car was not in use

Comment: What makes you think there is a deleted scene?

Comment: Because the film's script specifically mentions sat missiles which is a clear foreshadowing of an action scene where Bond would use them. Why would the screenwriters waste time going over the cars weapons in details or even show the car when it only has a 10 second appearance in the film?

Comment: @AceCabbie - most likely because BMW paid them a lot of money to showcase the car.

Comment: @AceCabbie They set up Bond's line to Wade about not touching any of the buttons in the car. That was enough payoff for me, at least.

Comment: Also, according to this IMDB comment - https://www.imdb.com/title/tt0113189/trivia/?item=tr2655784&ref_=ext_shr_lnk - it was because the deal with BMW came too late in production to use the gadgets.

Comment: @magarnicle this should be the answer. While I know there's no deleted footage, it seems out of place for a 007 film to have the cliche car setup scene but no car action scene. that makes sense that they didnt have time to coordinate a lot of stunts with it.